# Copy all "web.config" files using robocopy

Tags: robocopy

I need to write a robocopy command so that I can take the code (directory structure included) and copy it to another location. However, I don't need all the code. only the `web.config` files. I have the basic line, I'm simply unsure of what to add on the end so that it's only the specific files.

Guessing it's [here](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) but I can't decipher it.

Comment: post your actual command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only get web.config files, use

```
ROBOCOPY <your parameters> web.config
```

That 'web.config' is your file mask. Often, it will be something like '*.txt', but yours is so specific you won't need any wildcards.

Comment: When you post your command line, I'll amend my answer. Also, is this over a network? If so, use the /Z parameter to enable Restartable Mode.

Comment: Also, run it with /L first, to check what the output would be: it will just List the results.